# Box2dFlash - How to predict a collison?

Tags: flash, box2d, pool

I made this [monster cool game](http://cassinlwbg.facebook.joyent.us/quickpool/main.swf):

Just kidding.

My players are interested to see a line that predicts how the ball will bounce of wall or other balls.

Is that possible in **Box2dFlash**?

Answer (score 2):

Its possible using Box2d.

As [Todd2d](http://www.kerp.net/box2d/displaylesson.php?chapter=2&lesson=35) suggests but doesn't demonstrate, is create a parallel box2d world with everything the same then step through several time intervals and record what happens i.e. the position of the ball. You can then iterate through this list of points and draw lines showing where the ball will travel.

This will give the illusion of having predicted its path.

Comment: Nice strategy, does this create much overhead?

Comment: Well I suspect double but if you selectively add objects to whatever is in range of what you are predicting it would hit it could be very little I imagine. All depends on how many objects there are, if there were many dynamic objects that you had to predict it hitting against then probably as everytime you predicted the path you would have to reset / realign the two worlds.